# Find the previous and next 10 words of a given string inside a p-tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a project with html5. I'm searching a word in a div. I need to Highlight that word from the content and need to slice the content before and after that searched word.Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
        />


        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>


        <script>


            $(document).ready(function(){           
                $('#search').click(function() {                 
                    var keyword = $('.qid').val().replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/\s+$|^\s+/g, "");  
                    var containsString = keyword;               
                    if(keyword == ""){  

                    }else{
                        $('#search_content').css('overflow-y','scroll');
                    }                               
                    $("p").removeClass('show');
                    containsString = "p:contains("+containsString+")".replace("p:contains()","");                   

                    $(containsString).addClass('show');

                    $('#search_content').show();                                    


                });
                $('.srch').click(function(){
                    $('#displaybox2').show();
                });

            });

        </script>
        <style>
    .srch {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        cursor: pointer;
        float: right;
        height: 30px;
        margin-right: 27%;
        margin-top: 5px;
        padding: 2px 0 2px 3px;
        width: 30px;
    }
    #displaybox2 {
        border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        float: left;
        height: 552px;
        left: 1px;
        position: relative;
        width: 370px;
        z-index: 100000;
    }
    #search_content {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        height: 510px;
        display: none;
    }
    p,h2{
      display:none;
    }
    .qid{
        margin-top:10px;
    }
    .show{
        display: block;
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .highlight{
        background-color:#636F7C;
    }
    .srch_icon {
        width: 100%;
    }
        </style>
      </head>

      <body>

        <div id="displaybox2">
            <input class="qid" type="text"/><button id = "search">Search</button>       
            <div id = "search_content">     
                <p>Next evening was a lovely evening, and I walked out early to enjoy it. The sun was not yet quite down when I traversed the field-path near the top of the deep cutting. I would extend my walk for an hour, I said to myself, half an hour on and half an hour back, and it would then be time to go to my signal-man’s box.</p>
                <p>Before pursuing my stroll, I stepped to the brink, and mechanically looked down, from the point from which I had first seen him. I cannot describe the thrill that seized upon me, when, close at the mouth of the tunnel, I saw the appearance of a man, with his left sleeve across his eyes, passionately waving his right arm.</p>

            </div>
        </div>
      </body>

    </html>
```

If i search word 'extend' it returns the answer as

> Next evening was a lovely evening, and I walked out early to enjoy it. The sun was not yet quite down when I traversed the field-path near the top of the deep cutting. I would extend my walk for an hour, I said to myself, half an hour on and half an hour back, and it would then be time to go to my signal-man’s box.

But i need the answer like  below

> ....near the top of the deep cutting. I would **extend** my walk for an hour, I said to myself, half an hour....

Edit:

> I need the 10 words after and before the keyword. If the keyword is
>   exists more than once, it will also display 10 words after and before
>   the keyword. Is it clear for you. help me out

http://jsfiddle.net/3fTD3/

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3):

maybe something like this:

```
$('#search').click(function() {                 
    var keyword = $('.qid').val().replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/\s+$|^\s+/g, ""),
        containsString = keyword;         

    if (keyword == "") {  

    }
    else {
        $('#search_content').css('overflow-y','scroll');
    }   

    if ($("p:contains('" + keyword + "')").length) {
        var p = $("p:contains('" + keyword + "')"),
            html = p.html(),
            regex = new RegExp("" + keyword, "gi"),
            highlighted = html.replace(regex, "<strong>" + keyword + "</strong>");

        p.html(highlighted);
    }

    $("p").removeClass('show');
    $('#search_content').show();
});
```

Comment: @Alex Thanks. I need to slice the string before and after that highlighted word. Can u help me

Comment: jega what do you need exactly? if the keyword exists more than once, what should happen? Shall the other words be wrapped in spans, paragraphes, ..?

Comment: @Alex I need the 10 words after and before the keyword. If the keyword is exists more than once, it will also display 10 words after and before the keyword. Is it clear for you. help me out

Comment: i updated your question because it was pretty much not what you actually need